# OTA via BLE on Cypress CYBLE-222014-01 Module

Tags: bluetooth-low-energy, soc, psoc, ota

I have developed an application using the CYBLE-222014-01 module which acquires a set of data and transmits it over BLE. Now I would like to add OTA functionality to this project, however the application note is not that clear when explaining how a fixed stack bootloader is to be implemented. If anyone has a clearer idea it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you aware of the 50-page application note AN-97060, which is a Guide to OTA Firmware Update for your module?

Comment: Yes, but this application note is not that clear on the actual implementation of the code itself. Thanks

Comment: Looks like there are example projects and step-by-step instructions of how to combine their fixed-stack bootloader project with your BLE project. If still stuck, you could try the Infineon (which bought Cypress) community forums for specific help.

Comment: Ok, will do thanks a lot !